# single quote replacement problem in php

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression patter which similar to this

```
$pattern ="/[^\w]/";
```

But it should hide html syntax.

```
$string = preg_replace($pattern,'',$str);
```

Comment: 'hide HTML syntax'? What's tahat supposed to mean? An example perhaps?

Comment: But it should hide html syntax. I don't undertand, talking about stripping html tags if yes there is strip_tags

Comment: Ehh, what? Can you please actually tell what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not one hundred pourcent sure about what you mean by "hide HTML syntax" but if your content is some html and you want to strip out the html tags use [`strip_tags`](http://fr.php.net/strip_tags) function.

so in your example:

```
$pattern ="/[^\w]/"; 
$string = preg_replace($pattern,'',html_entity_decode(strip_tags($str)));
```

Comment: When i use this pattern "/[^\w]/".It removes all spaces in string.I need a pattern that should have slimier task but it should not escape white spaces.

Comment: @Deepak: sorry I don't understand, can you edit your question with input and output you need.

Comment: I have a string like this :

Canada’s most cosmopolitan city is situated on beautiful Lake

When I use this code:

$str = "Canada’s most cosmopolitan city is situated on beautiful Lake";
$string = preg_replace("/[^\w]/",' ',$str);


It gives me output as :

p Canada rsquo s most cosmopolitan city is situated on beautiful Lake